# Application that uses MetroModernUI can't be started

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I've worked on a project for a couple of days, but it won't start anymore. 
I've searched everywhere on the internet but nothing helped. I"m using the framework MetroModernUI perhaps it has something to do with that?

Packages.config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="MetroModernUI" version="1.3.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Program class :

```
  [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Login());
    }
```

I've disabled the visual studio hosting process. That didn't worked. 
One thing is strange in my debug properties the settings won't load.

Can somebody help me ?

Comment: What error do you get when you try to run? What have you tried to solve the problem? Does it work if you copy the project to a new PC, or even a new folder? Does it work if you create a new project whith the config and program you posted here?

Comment: When I click on start, in the bottom left is standing "Loading symbols for Metroframework.Fonts.dll" Then shows up "ready". But the program doesn't show up. When I open the program debug folder, it keeps loading for a long time but nothing shows up. I've tried it on several other pc but that doesn't work. Also I've just changed the map name.  I"ve noticed that when I keep visual studio in "Ready" state. After 1 minute it shows the error "The source file is different from when the module was built. Would you like the debugger to use it anyway".